# Processes not in enforce mode although a profile is defined?

Tags: apparmor

I have defined the following profile

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/convert.im6 {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /usr/bin/convert.im6 mr,

  /** mrwlkix,
  set rlimit as <= 8G,
}
```

and loaded it via `aa-enforce /usr/bin/convert`.
However, newly started processes of this binary do not show up in `aa-status` at all.

Could it be because they are started with `nice -n +19 convert ...`?
Or because another process with a defined profile is starting them?

What is going wrong? How do I get AppArmor do enforce those processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed caused by the profile of the parent application.

I have created the following snippet and `#include`d it in the beginning of all profiles that may start one of the programs:

```
/usr/bin/convert.im6 Pix,
```